# R: Count number of new observations compared to a previous groups

Tags: r

I would like to know the number of new observations that occurred between groups.

If I have the following data:

| Year | Observation |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | A |
| 2009 | A |
| 2009 | B |
| 2010 | A |
| 2010 | B |
| 2010 | C |

I wound like the output to be

| Year | New_Obsevation_Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | 2 |
| 2010 | 1 |

I am new to R and don't really know how to move forward. I have tried using the count function in the tidyverse package but still can't figure out.

Comment: Why are the new observations in 2009 3 and not 2?

Comment: @GKi Thanks for pointing that out. It is supposed to be 2 not 3. Just a typo.

Comment: This is unclear. Why is it supposed to be 2? What are the conditions that need to be satisfied in order for the final outcome to be 2 in both cases? It seems to me that all you want is count the total number of observations by `Year` and then remove just the first row. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` in `Reduce`:

```
y <- split(x$Observation, x$Year)
data.frame(Year = names(y), nNew =
 diff(lengths(Reduce(union, y, NULL, accumulate = TRUE))))
#  Year nNew
#1 2009    2
#2 2010    1
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Year     Observation
2009    A
2009    A
2009    B
2010    A
2010    B
2010    C")
```